# visualization of the density distribution function on a 3d sphere

Tags: plot, rendering, distribution, probability-density, density-plot

What should be the function to get the graph in the figure. I.e. some density J is given. I'm looking for a function f(J) that returns a color in the range from blue(density is min) to red(density is max). If J is constant, the entire sphere has a uniform red color. Otherwise, if J isn't constant, the sphere have color in range from blue to red as stated earlier.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwpiM.jpg)

Comment: How about `(255*((f(J)-min)/(max-min)), 0, 255*(1.0-(f(J)-min)/(max-min)))` ?

Comment: I want to get result as in the picture. Your decision will mix red with blue.

Comment: i found out, the function that is needed looks like:
J:[0,1]; 
color =  J*(1,0,0) + (0,0, 0.5) - J*(0,0,1)